# am not able to get any content from js file when i run the app.It will be better if someone help me

Tags: mean

Why am i not able to get my js file when i run the app..

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="movieApp">
    <head>
        <title> Movies I like..</title>
        <base href="/">
    </head>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <a ui-sref="movies">Movies</a>
        </div>

        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/movies.js"></script>
</html>
```

app.js

```app
var movieApp = angular.module('movieApp', ['ui.router']);

movieApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('movies');
    $stateProvider
    .state('movies', {
        'url' : '/movies',
        templateUrl : '/views/movies.html'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

movies.html

```movie
    <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="movie" placeholder="Enter the Movie Name..">
        <button ng-click="createMovie()" 
        ng-show="isEditting">Create Movie</button>
        <button ng-click="updateTask(movie, 'save')" 
        ng-show="!isEditting">Save Movie</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div ng-show="movies.length > 0">
            <table border="1px solid" style="border-collapse: collapse;margin-bottom: 30px;">
                <tr><th>Movies</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
                    <td>{{movie.movieName}}</td>
                    <td><button ng-click="edit(movie)">Edit</button></td>
                    <td><button ng-click="delete(movie)">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

movies.js file

```
var app= angular.module('movieApp');

app.controller('Moviecntrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.movies=[
     {movieName: 'DDLJ'},
     {movieName: 'Jack Reacher'},
     {movieName: 'Mission Impossible'}
];
});
```

[for some reference i had attached the image of the folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ssq96.jpg)

can anyone pls help me to solve this problem.Am a beginner so it is little bit tough to find where i did a mistake.

Comment: check your base href path.  i make a copy of your code in plknr i just remove the base and html5 mode. to false, and relocate the paths of your js and works.

Answer (score 0):

I used node js in server side

server.js

```js
var express = require("express");
var path=require('path')
var app = express();
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/../client')));
app.listen(PORT, function() {
 // body...
 console.log("We are connected to PORT-",PORT);
});
```

Check for the base href path you define it match with the paths where your files are located, i delete the base and html5 mode to false, and the relative paths works. i put the  [example](https://embed.plnkr.co/bCvkVvOb26qN1SgiLGdr/)

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="movieApp">
    <head>
        <title> Movies I like..</title>

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.4.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="movies.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <a ui-sref="movies">Movies</a>
        </div>

        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
    angular.module('movieApp', ['ui.router'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('movies');
    $stateProvider
    .state('movies', {
        'url' : '/movies',
        templateUrl : 'movies.html'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
});
```

**movies.js**

```
angular.module('movieApp').controller('Moviecntrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.movies=[
     {movieName: 'DDLJ'},
     {movieName: 'Jack Reacher'},
     {movieName: 'Mission Impossible'}
];
});
```

Comment: tqsm sir.I used the above code but when i run the app using node server am not able to get the output